# C++ : int* / float* to char*, why get different result using reinterpret_cast?

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

- *int** to *char** :
  `int* pNum = new int[1];
  pNum[0] = 57;
  char* pChar = reinterpret_cast< char* >(pNum);`

  > Result : pChar[0] = '9'; //'9' ASCII 57
- *float** to *char** :
  `float* pFloat = new float[1];
  pFloat[0] = 57; //assign the same value as before
  char* pChar = reinterpret_cast< char* >(pFloat);`

> Result : pChar[0] = 'a';

**So why I'm getting two different results ?**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: because bits of `float` and `int` mean different things

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `float` and `int` are data types which are (usually) represented by four bytes:

```
b1 b2 b3 b4
```

However, those bytes are interpreted quite differently across the two types - if they wouldn't, there would be hardly any need for two types.

Now if you reinterpret the pointers to pointers-to-char, the result points only to the first byte, as this is the length of a `char`:

```
b1 b2 b3 b4
^^
your char* points to here
```

As said, this first byte has a very different meaning for the two data types, and this is why the representation as a `char` in general differs.

---

**Application to your example:**

The number `57` in float (IEEE754 Single precision 32-bit) is represented in bits as

```
01000010 01100100 00000000 00000000
```

In contrast, the representation in a 32-bit integer format is

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00111001
```

Here the number seems to be represented in "big-endian" format, where the most important byte (the one which changes the value of the int the most) comes first. As mentioned by @Jean-FrançoisFabre, in your PC it seems to be the other way round, but nevermind. For both conversions, I used [this site](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_signed_int.html?decimal=053055).

Now your `char*` pointers point to the first of those 8-bit-blocks, respectively. And obviously they're different.

Answer (score 8):

You have this because floating point values don't use the same encoding as integer values (IEEE encoding with mantissa+exponent or something like that)

Besides, I suppose you're running a little endian CPU, otherwise your first test would have yielded 0 (I mean `'\0'`).